# Dictionary.Value changes with the change of object assigned to it

Tags: c#, dictionary, object

I am trying to make a Dictionary of (string, WI), where WI is a class I defined.

The code looks like this:

```
namespace Tracking
{
    class Program
    {
        static public Dictionary<string, WI> Dict = new Dictionary<string, WI>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WI oWI = new WI(some_arg);
            string key = "mykey";
            if (!Dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                Dict.Add(key, oWI);
            }

            var before = Dict[key];

            oWI = new WI(another_arg);

            var after = Dict[key];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after changing `oWI`, every thing inside `Dict[key].Value` also changes, i.e. the values of "before" and "after" are not the same.

It seems like there is a connection between them. How can I break the connection? Shouldn't dictionary make its own copy of the WI object? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not true. Actually `oWI` is a variable. That is like a motorway sign to a city which for a example shows the direction to London. Now you keep the text on the sign but change the  direction to  Paris. What happened? Have you changed London to be Paris or have you just changed the sign? You haven't changed the dictionary which still stores the old instance and not the new.

Comment: Cannot re-create. If I put in a trivial `WI` then `before` gets the value originally added to the dictionary, this is not changed by updating `oWI`. Please include a minimal re-create that shows this behaviour.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Richard I will edit the questions. I was trying to keep it short.

Comment: How you check that both instances are not same?

Comment: You can achive behaviour you has by having shared state between instances of `WI` class. `static` properties for example

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR: The reported behaviour does not appear using the supplied code

Likely `WI` is doing something "clever" which cannot be re-created without the definition of `WI`.

#### Demonstration

The following code outputs

```
Before: One
After: One
```

ie. changing the reference `oWI` does not change other references to an object previously referred to by `oWI`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WI
{
    public string Data { get; private set; }

    public WI(string x)
    {
        Data = x;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static public Dictionary<string, WI> Dict = new Dictionary<string, WI>();
    const string some_arg = "One";
    const string another_arg = "Two";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WI oWI = new WI(some_arg);
        string key = "mykey";
        if (!Dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            Dict.Add(key, oWI);
        }

        var before = Dict[key];
        Console.WriteLine($"Before: {before.Data}");

        oWI = new WI(another_arg);

        var after = Dict[key];
        Console.WriteLine($"After: {after.Data}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy `oWI1` object to another new object. if `WI` class is reference type it need to implement [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and make deep clone. let two objects point different refer.

For example:

`WI` implement `ICloneable` the do `Clone` method, it will return an new `WI` object.

```
public class WI : ICloneable
{
    public int age1 { get; set; }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new WI() { age1 = this.age1 };
    }
}
```

when you use

```
var after = Dict[key].Clone() as WI;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dictionary just keeps the reference to the created object oWI. So if oWI (which the dictionary is pointing to) is changed this will also be reflected in the dict.

Consider creating the object directly in the dictionary to make access to the object isolated to the dictionary. Like so:

```
string key = "mykey";
if (!Dict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    Dict.Add(key, new WI(some_arg));
}
```

Comment: Changing `oWI` does not change the dictionary (try the original code: the reported behaviour does not occur). You're mixing up reference and referent.

Comment: (To clarify) Changing the state of the object referred to by `oWI` will lead to the change being visible by other references to the same object. Changing `oWI` to refer to a different object will not be seen by other references to the original object.